# is it possible to use salience and timer together?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

Is it true that rule B should be triggered before A? Because it doesn't work for me.

```
rule A
        salience 0
        timer(int: 20s)
    when
...

rule B
        salience 1
        timer(int: 20s)
    when
...
```

Edit:
Conditions of the two are equal, as thus both are supposed to be triggered on the same event and condition was omitted for clearness. The point is that I would like to trigger rules after 20s timeout and make them ordinal is that possible?.

Answer (score 1):

Rules with a timer are scheduled for execution as soon as the condition evaluates to true. You haven't shown the conditions for A and B, so further analysis isn't possible. It is very likely that the two timers aren't started at the very same point in time, so the expiry times can be ordered A < B. If you need B before A, run the timer for B. Add a conditional element for letting A fire without a timer and let the consequence of B insert a fact to 
meet this conditional element. Roughly:

```
rule B
timer(int: 20s)
when...
then
    insert( new TriggerForA() )
end

rule A
when
    $t: TriggerForA()
    ...
then
    delete( $t );
end
```

Comment: could you please review my clarified question?

Comment: This doesn't tell me much more. Salience orders RHS executions, but it does not have any effect on how timers are started or actions resulting after timer expiry are executed. - If LHS of A equals LHS of B - why do you need two rules in the first place?